# Hadoop cannot see my input directory

Tags: java, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop2

I am following the [Apache Map Reduce tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v1.0) and I am at the point of assigning input and output directories. I created both directories here:

```
~/projects/hadoop/WordCount/input/
~/projects/hadoop/WordCount/output/
```

but when I run `fs`, the file and directory are not found. I am running as ubuntu user and it owns the directories and the input file.

**Based on a proposed solution below, I then tried:**

Found my hdfs directory `hdfs dfs -ls /` which is `/tmp`
I created input/ and output/ inside `/tmp` with `mkdir`

**Tried to copy local .jar to.hdfs:**

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ~projects/hadoop/WordCount/wc.jar /tmp
```

**Received:**

```
copyFromLocal: `~projects/hadoop/WordCount/wc.jar': No such file or directory
```

[image]

Any troubleshooting ideas? Thanks

Comment: Create the input dir with `hadoop fs -mkdir /input` and then run the wordcount jar as `hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount /input /output`. Let me know if this solves

Comment: Thanks, I think that will work! I was able to create input/ in hdfs.  One question: How do I get my input data file into hdfs /input and do I need to create /output in the same way, or is that local? I presume your post will explain and thanks

Comment: I have explained it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapReduce expects the `Input` and `Output` paths to be the directories in HDFS and not local unless the Cluster is configured in Local mode. Also the Input directory must exist and the Output should not.

**For example:**

If Input is `/mapreduce/wordcount/input/`, this directory must be created with all the input files in it. Use HDFS commands to create them.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /mapreduce/wordcount/input/
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal file1 file2 file3 /mapreduce/wordcount/input/
```

*`file1 file2 file3` are locally available input files*

And if the Output is `/examples/wordcount/output/`. The parent directories must exist but not the  `output/` directory. Hadoop creates it on the job execution.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /examples/wordcount/
```

The jar used for the job, in this case `wc.jar` should reside locally and on execution provide the absolute or the relative local path to the command.

So the final command would look like

```
hadoop jar /path/where/the/jar/is/wc.jar ClassName /mapreduce/wordcount/input/ /examples/wordcount/output/
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. It really helped me understand the problem and yes, the solution worked and better yet,I understand what I was doing wrong and know better going forward.

Answer (score 1):

As the hadoop Invalid Input Exception suggests it can not find location "/home/ubuntu/projects/hadoop/WordCount/input".

Is it local or HDFS path? I think it is local that's why the input Exception happening.

To execute a jar file you have to put jar in the HDFS directory. And the input and output directories also have to be in HDFS.

Use copyFromLocal command to copy the jar from local to hadoop directory as:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal <localsrc>/wc.jar hadoop-dir
```